# FileGDB: 'make' fails for sample (Ubuntu 15)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I've been searching quite some time now how to make te FileGDB Samples compile (I assume that when I fix this, I'll be able to compile GDAL with FileGDB support. It compiles fine without.). I've done it before on Debian 7, and compared notes to several sites. I used c:\temp to download and unpack, and then copied it to /usr/local/FileGDB_API

Here are the steps I followed (x64): 
http://hydrogeotools.blogspot.be/2013/07/install-gdal-with-file-gdb-and.html

download filegdb api from esri, make sure to select 64bit for your 64bit machine etc, unpack in ~/src/ and 'install' by copying files to a more relevant place

```
sudo cp -r ~/src/FileGDB_API /usr/local/
```

and then fix links by opening /etc/ld.so.conf

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf
```

and put following line into the file,
/usr/local/FileGDB_API/lib
 save and close file, then update links

```
sudo ldconfig
```

test it

```
cd ~/src/FileGDB_API/samples
make
cd ~/src/FileGDB_API/samples/bin
./Querying
```

But when I run make, I get this:

```
make -C Domains
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/local/FileGDB_API/samples/Domains'
g++ -fPIC -O3 -m64 -W -fexceptions -D_CONSOLE -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DUNIX -D_REENTRANT -DFILEGDB_API -D__USE_FILE_OFFSET64 -DUNIX_FILEGDB_API -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../../include -I.  -c Domains.cpp
g++ -fPIC -O3 -m64 -W -fexceptions -D_CONSOLE -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DUNIX -D_REENTRANT -DFILEGDB_API -D__USE_FILE_OFFSET64 -DUNIX_FILEGDB_API -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../../include -I. -m64 -L"../../lib" -o ../bin/Domains ./Domains.o -lFileGDBAPI
./Domains.o: In function `main':
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8e): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::OpenGeodatabase(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe7): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1af): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::DeleteDomain(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x247): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::DeleteDomain(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x553): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::CreateDomain(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x58f): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6a4): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::GetDomainDefinition(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) const'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6f8): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x98e): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::CreateDomain(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9ca): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xba7): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::AlterDomain(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbe0): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd09): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase::OpenTable(std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, FileGDBAPI::Table&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd60): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xee2): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Table::AlterField(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf1b): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf9b): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorRecord(int, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1144): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::Table::AlterField(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x117d): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x11fd): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorRecord(int, int&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
Domains.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1314): undefined reference to `FileGDBAPI::ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:33: recipe for target '../bin/Domains' failed
make[1]: *** [../bin/Domains] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/FileGDB_API/samples/Domains'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'Domains' failed
make: *** [Domains] Error 2
```

It might be a more general mistake, I'm not that familiar with Linux yet, but I'd love some help/pointers.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 15 with the FileGDB_API 1.3 and 1.4 64 bit.

I found a solution: I had to compile GDAL with g++-4.8, not with g++-5.2.1 which is installed as standard compiler on my ubuntu 15

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
export CXX=g++-4.8
cd FileGDB_API_1_4/samples
make clean
make
cd gdal-2
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I'm interested to know how you found out the compiler needed to be downgraded?

Comment: I actually can't remember, it's some month ago. Thanks for the alternative method with the CXXFLAGS.

Comment: NP, although I might have posted prematurely - the build was ok but using the driver in anger caused segfaults. Recompiling with 4.8 did the trick after all and I guess was a less 'bleeding edge' method than just forcing the use of the latest compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, ESRI has updated their files. https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/blob/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1/FileGDB_API_1_5_1-64gcc51.tar.gz is dedicated for g++/gcc version 5.1 and newer.

With that, the FileGDB API compiles without error on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 using the default compiler versions.

See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292506/how-do-i-install-esri-file-gdb-api-in-ubuntu-16-04-so-qgis-2-8-can-see-it

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative method which doesn't require falling back to an older compiler. Setting the `D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` c++ compiler flag in the makefile in `gdal/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/filegdb/GNUmakefile` allows g++ to use the fgdb libs built with older versions of g++:

`CXXFLAGS := -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`

So in my GNUmakefile, the top few lines read:

```
include ../../../GDALmake.opt

OBJ =   FGdbDatasource.o FGdbDriver.o FGdbLayer.o FGdbUtils.o FGdbResultLayer.o

CPPFLAGS    :=  -I../generic  $(FGDB_INC) $(CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS := -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0  // <---------------------------- I added this line

default:    $(O_OBJ:.o=.$(OBJ_EXT))
```

Some reference info was found [here](https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/pull/1048/commits/239ca9aa8022820d56798f06ea6836162a0892ea) and, critically, [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/filegdb-api/).

Update: Although it appears to compile with no problems, running the autotest modules from gdal after the build results in a catastrophic failure on the fgdb tests (specifically, when `fgdb_driver.CreateDatasource(path)` is called). Recompiling with g++-4.8 was a working solution.